# How to replace click button with hold?

Tags: java, button, jbutton

Hi i want to make my button work buy holding it for a set number of seconds instead of clicking on it, the button in question simply opens a new JFrame,

```
 button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                frame.dispose();
                new SecondFrame();
            }
        });
```

thanks,

Comment: Use `button.addMouseListener()` instead... You will have `mouseReleased()` and `mousePressed()` methods... You can use these 2 to get the number of seconds the button was pressed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Codebender, you can use `MouseListener` instead.Which have  `mousePressed()` and `mouseReleased()` methods.I have calculated the time by `currentTimeMillis()` between each successive press/release.

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
JButton b = new JButton();
f.add(b);
f.pack();
f.setVisible(true);
b.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
    long start_time, stop_time;
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        start_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("" + start_time);
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        stop_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("" + stop_time);
        if (stop_time - start_time > 1000) {
            new JFrame().setVisible(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {}
});
```

You can increase or decrease the given time.Also look at [MouseAdapter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html).